# how to include python code as a part of cloud formation template in aws?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have some python code/project to so some ETL work, processing some XML/json docs. code sample below, is one of the connection.py file from my project. i have few other files, which reads and processes the XML document. I want to include the project/code as part of the cloud formation template, as a lambda. how can i do this?

file - connection.py

```
import json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

my_eshost = 'search-sampledomain-bqfy4dd5xuljut33l6jdz7gkqi.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'

aws_auth = AWS4Auth( '*******','******', 'us-east-1', 'es')

es = Elasticsearch(hosts = [{'host': my_eshost, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth=aws_auth, use_ssl=True, verify_certs=True, connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection)

print(json.dumps(es.info()))
```

Comment: Where/how are you wanting this code to be used? Will it be an AWS Lambda function, or perhaps executed via an EC2 User Data script?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - yes, I want it to be a lambda function. I do have couple of more files though, along with the connection code , i posted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following should be helpful:

- [Uploading Local Artifacts to an S3 Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-cli-package.html)

This enables, among other things, to use your **local files**, e.g. `connection.py` for lambda function body. When you package your stack for the upload to CloudFormation, the AWS CLI will upload **automatically** your file to S3 and use it as a source for the function:

> If you specify a file, the command directly uploads it to the S3 bucket. After uploading the artifacts, the command returns a copy of your template, **replacing references to local artifacts with the S3 location** where the command uploaded the artifacts. Then, you can use the returned template to create or update a stack.

Comment: thanks. I was creating template and creating stack in aws cloudformation. this looks like , I have to do this from my local machine, were i specify path to the local folder , where my source code is. I wonder if i can upload my zipped code to s3 bucket first then reference it's path in the template, i'm writing in aws console.

Comment: @ozil Yes you can upload to s3 and the specify bucket and key for the zip in the CFN template for the lambda.

Comment: @ozil No problem. Glad I could help.